# non-blocking sockets with state machine

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nio

I am trying to write own client server logic with NIO in Java.
Im my solution i use frames to provide communication.
First byte keeps information about request type, second three bytes keep size of frame.
If header is received then my class waiting for rest data. Problem appears when i want wan send big frame ex. big file (30MB) or something dynamically generated on client side. I want to keep non-blocking idea (i assume number of thread should be equal to number of Logic CPUs and many users should be executed in one thread) because in once time many users should can sending own files (same parts). Thread for all users should be balanced (small parts of data for each). I have written a basic class for server and class for StateMachine. In current version the active machine state is executed after frame is completed. Its means, i need to store frames before specific state were executed. I could solve it by creating in each time new ByteBuffer with size equal to frame size, and after that i could remove it. 

And my question: is approach good ?
To interpret ByteBuffer data i use own class similar to DataInputStream.

Example case (each connected client keeps own states):

```
Raw state: // without logged user
- disconnect operation
- login operation:
    Admin state:
    - list plugins operation
    - add plugin operation
    - remove plugin operation
    - logout operation
    - disconnect operation
    Guest state:
    // - guest operations here...
    // ...
    // other states...
```

For small buffers I could execute specific state for each time with additional flag like FRAME_FINISHED but it little interferes with DataInputStream, because it require to write complicated operation source for complicated frames and joins available data inside ByteBuffer in specific types for DataInputStream during read operation (ex. readInt32 when one buffer ends and second starts).

Comment: I suggest you have a look at grizzly and if it's possible you'd better use it : https://grizzly.java.net/